# Catch if UITextField want a num / decimal / default pad in a Third-Party Keyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a Custom Keyboard for my own application and I need to know if the UITexfield focused want a Decimal or Default version of my Third-Party Keyboard.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func checkAboutKeyboardType() {
    switch self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardType {
        case UIKeyboardType.Default? :
            print("Default")
            break
        case UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad? :
            print("Decimal Pad")
            break
        case UIKeyboardType.NumberPad? :
            print("Number Pad")
            break
        default :
            print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Oldskool Ohhh really sorry for the insanity... It was a simple copy/paste from my own code and i was really angry :/

Comment: No problem, I didn't think you did it on purpose, but it adds no real value to the code and might offend people. Therefor I edited it out.

Comment: @Oldskool I'm totally agree with you, thanks for the edit.